# Typical CppCMS memory consumption

Tags: c++, memory, optimization, cppcms

I'm developing a CppCMS app, for running on my ARM-based custom board. I'm running CppCMS behind Lighttpd using fastcgi. But apparently CppCMS consumes far more memory than Lighttpd does (50+ MB), which comes as a surprise to me.

**DISCLAIMER:** The memory consumption listed above was obtained using 'ps' applet of busybox, which *may* have issues regarding the reported memory use. Hence do NOT let my ramblings here discourage you from giving Artyoms excellent CppCMS a spin.

Before digging deeper into this, I would like to hear if anyone has some numbers on "common" consumption of CppCMS as a function of site complexity.

My setup: ARMv5TE, CodeSourcery GCC v 4.3.3, site includes 4 pages, and uses 2 types of forms.

**update**

I'm running CppCMS 1.0.4.

There is no SQL database, only a very simple C++ datastructure. Performing a "sizeof" on the combined set of objects in the structure is below 1 KiB.

My config-file looks as follows:

```
"service" : {
        "api" : "http",
        "port" : 8080
},
"security" : {
    "csrf" : {
        "enable" : true,
    }
},
"session" : {  

    "expire" : "renew",  
    "timeout" : 604800,  
    "location" : "client",  
    "client" :      {  
            "hmac" :        "sha1",  
            "hmac_key" :    "............"  
    }      

    }
```

The reported 50+ MB memory consumption was dermined running 'ps' command on the deployment linux-box.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application, cache usage and many other factors.

For example, in this sample program: http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/benchmarks_all the usage is few MB (including lighttpd).

In some it would be several MB in some keeping in memory database it may be huge.

Also it is also important to understand how do you measure the application memory consumption.

Comment: Hi Artyom, Kudos for CppCMS :-) I'll add more specifics to my question.

Comment: I've tried to list some info regarding the application. The memory consumption is still suprising in my view.